# Как сделать VKbottle userbot?

Tags: python, вконтакте, vkbottle

```
from vkbottle.user import User, Message
import re, asyncio
from vkbottle import VKAPIError
import mysql.connector
import random
from random import randint
#from roles_vk import Permission
from loguru import logger
from config import settings
import requests
import os
import json
logger.remove()

user = User(token='')


@user.on.message(text=[".invite", ".invite <argument>", ".invite <argument> <user_link>"])
async def invite_user_to_chats(message: Message, argument: str, user_link: str):
    chat_id = message.peer_id
    uid = message.from_id
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=settings['host'],
        user=settings["user"],
        password=settings["password"],
        database=settings["database"]
    )
    curs = mydb.cursor()
    curs = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    command_args = message.text.split(' ')
    pattern = r"vk\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)"
    match = re.search(pattern, user_link)

    if match:
        response = await user.users.get(user_ids=match.group(1))
        user_id = response[0].id
    else:
        user_id = int(user_link.split('[id')[1].split('|')[0])
    if len(command_args) == 3:
        curs.execute(f'SELECT dostup FROM perms WHERE vk = {uid} AND dostup = "2" OR vk = {uid} AND dostup = "3" OR vk = {uid} AND dostup = "1"')
        myres = curs.fetchone()
        
        if myres is None:
            await message.answer('У Вас нет прав!')
        else:
            if user_id is not None:
                if argument == 'G':
                    await user.messages.add_chat_user(chat_id=2, user_id=user_id)
                    await user.messages.add_chat_user(chat_id=3, user_id=user_id)
                    await message.answer('Пользователь успешно добавлен в беседу')
                elif argument == 'M':
                    await user.messages.add_chat_user(chat_id=2, user_id=user_id)
                    await user.messages.add_chat_user(chat_id=4, user_id=user_id)
                    await message.answer('Пользователь успешно добавлен в беседу')
                elif argument is None:
                    await message.answer('Некорректный аргумент! Допустимые значения: G, M')
            else:
                await message.answer('Вы не указали пользователя!')

    else:
        print('5')
        await message.answer('Пожалуйста, укажите аргумент (G или M) и ссылку или id пользователя после команды !invite!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  user.run_forever()
```

Нужна помощь, не реагирует на команду .invite